# How to create a unique index when a collection is created? or before it created?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, unique

we are using mongo to store some SASS business data, and collection name like: "company_id_user",  they are create dynamic, and we want to create some unique indexes once the collection create, I don't find a way to solve this.

If we can't create a unique index when the document is generated, the document may have generated non unique data when concurrent, and we can't create it any more.

and we don't want to solve it from code, but from mongodb self.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index before the collection is created. For example, I don't have a collection called as `users`, and I am creating an unique index on the `email` field.

From the `mongo` shell or `mongosh`:

```
db.users.createIndex( { email: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

This will create the empty collection (with name as `users`) as well as the unique index on the `email` field. And, you can verify the index creation with this command:

```
db.users.getIndexes()
```

Also, refer MongoDB Manual about [Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).